# How to do uncertainty propagation within pandas dataframe (geochemical data reduction)

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, montecarlo

I have geochemical analyses (isotope ratios with associated analytical error) for which I am trying to calculate the chemical concentration based on my standard calibration curve.

I have four days of data, each with their own standard curves. I've already done a york regression on the standards and achieved the following matrix of intercepts (a), slopes (b), and associated errors:

```
york = {'date':['Jun27', 'Jun28', 'Jun29', 'Jun30'],
        'a':[1.2013, 1.0057, 1.1462, 0.3874],
        'b':[44138,41246,43311,49830],
        'siga':[0.2795,0.2791,0.2189,0.3641],
        'sigb':[531.7,873.7,727.26,1251.7]}

yk = pd.DataFrame(york) 
yk.set_index('date', inplace = True)
```

Such that [Ti] = 49Ti/30Si16O * b + a

I also have the data; normally I read it in as a dataframe using

```
df30 = pd.read_clipboard()
```

because it's a big chunk and that way I get the column names from the copied spreadsheet. But for example's sake, here's a few data points:

```
Jun30 = {'File':['LB13-LP41-10-ZR.asc', 'LB13-LP41-19-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-1-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-18ZR.asc'],
         '49Ti/30Si16O':[0.000405567, 0.000272094, 0.000320981, 0.000153742],
         '1 se err':[2.61586E-06, 7.65216E-07, 1.32338E-06, 1.53561E-06]}
        df30 = pd.DataFrame(Jun30)
        df30.set_index('File', inplace = True)
```

I'd like to do a monte-carlo uncertainty propagation of the analytical error plus the standard calibration error, such that

[Ti]+/- [Tierr] = (49Ti/30Si16O+/-1 se err) * (b +/- sigb) + (a +/- siga)

What is the easiest/most economical way to do this within the dataframe? Ideally I'd like to add two columns: '[Ti]' and 'Ti err' to the dataframe, but I don't know how to iterate through each row and refer to the correct values.

Normally doing this in MATLAB with arrays, I'd do something like the following:

```
    RTi = [data for Ti ratio]
    RTierr = [associated errors]
    %etc...
    N = numel(RTi)
    Ti = zeros(N,1);
    Tierr = zeros(N,1);

    for i = 1:N
        j = zeros(1e5,1);
        k = zeros(1e5,1);

        for n = 1:1e5
        a(n) = normrnd(intercept,sigintercept);
        b(n) = normrnd(slope,sigslope);
        k(n) = normrnd(RTi,RTierr);
        j(n) = k(n).*b(n)+a(n)
    end
    Ti(i) = mean(j);
    Tierr(i) = std(j);
end
```

But this is a little clunky and I'm pretty sure learning how to do this with python in dataframes will be easier and hopefully faster.

Answer (score 0):

### Given data in the following form:

```
Jun27 = {'File':['LB13-LP41-10-ZR.asc', 'LB13-LP41-19-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-1-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-18ZR.asc'],
         '49Ti/30Si16O':[0.000405567, 0.000272094, 0.000320981, 0.000153742],
         '1 se err':[2.61586E-06, 7.65216E-07, 1.32338E-06, 1.53561E-06], 'date': 'Jun27'}
Jun28 = {'File':['LB13-LP41-10-ZR.asc', 'LB13-LP41-19-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-1-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-18ZR.asc'],
         '49Ti/30Si16O':[0.000405567, 0.000272094, 0.000320981, 0.000153742],
         '1 se err':[2.61586E-06, 7.65216E-07, 1.32338E-06, 1.53561E-06], 'date': 'Jun28'}
Jun29 = {'File':['LB13-LP41-10-ZR.asc', 'LB13-LP41-19-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-1-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-18ZR.asc'],
         '49Ti/30Si16O':[0.000405567, 0.000272094, 0.000320981, 0.000153742],
         '1 se err':[2.61586E-06, 7.65216E-07, 1.32338E-06, 1.53561E-06], 'date': 'Jun29'}
Jun30 = {'File':['LB13-LP41-10-ZR.asc', 'LB13-LP41-19-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-1-ZR.asc', 'LB13-MB50-18ZR.asc'],
         '49Ti/30Si16O':[0.000405567, 0.000272094, 0.000320981, 0.000153742],
         '1 se err':[2.61586E-06, 7.65216E-07, 1.32338E-06, 1.53561E-06], 'date': 'Jun30'}
```

- Only one day of data was provided, so that day has been used for all days in this example

### Concat all the data:

```
data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(Jun27), pd.DataFrame(Jun28), pd.DataFrame(Jun29), pd.DataFrame(Jun30)])
```

- Note the addition of the date column

[image]

### Merge `yk` (from the example) and `data`:

```
df = pd.merge(yk, data)
```

[image]

- It's easier to perform the calculations with all of the data in the same `DataFrame`
- Merge is on the `date` column contained in both `DataFrames`

### Create calculations:

```
df['Ti'] = df['49Ti/30Si16O'] * df.b + df.a

df['49Ti/30Si16O_error_min'] = df['49Ti/30Si16O'] - df['1 se err']
df['49Ti/30Si16O_error_max'] = df['49Ti/30Si16O'] + df['1 se err']
df['b_error_min'] = df.b - df.sigb
df['b_error_max'] = df.b + df.sigb
df['a_error_min'] = df.a - df.siga
df['a_error_max'] = df.a + df.siga
df['Ti_min'] = df['49Ti/30Si16O_error_min'] * df['b_error_min'] + df['a_error_min']
df['Ti_max'] = df['49Ti/30Si16O_error_max'] * df['b_error_max'] + df['a_error_max']
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm specifically looking for how to iterate through the dataframe so I can do a monte carlo simulation. Adding and subtracting error values doesn't fully capture the uncertainties.

Answer (score 0):

The go-to function for "iterating through a dataframe" is df.apply.  With `pd.DataFrame.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=0)`, which is the default, the iteration is across columns operating on all rows at once.  With `pd.DataFrame.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1)`, the iteration is row-by-row, giving f(x) access to all columns, which is what you asked for.  However, looking at your matlab, it's not exactly what you need, because you are doing more than iterating row-by-row.  Your inner `n` loop presumes that you have all data pertaining to the
`RTi` and `RTierr` columns, which row-by-row does not give you.

The `apply` function has a cousin, `assign`, which lets you use `apply`-like functionality to create new columns.  While pandas was designed to work with numeric data (ints, floats, complex, etc), you can put any datatype into a DataFrame, including 10K element arrays for your montecarlo simulation:

```
df = df.assign(a=lambda x: [np.normal.random(x['intercept'],x['sigintercept']) for n in range (0,10000)], \
               b=lambda x: [np.normal.random(x['slope'],x['sigslope']) for n in range (0,10000)], \
               k=lambda x: [np.normal.random(x['RTi'], x['RTierr']) for n in range (0,10000)], \
               j=lambda x: np.dot(x['k'], x['b']).add(x['a']),
               Ti=lambda x: np.mean(x['j']),
               Tierr=lambda x: np.std(x[j]).drop(columns=['a', 'b', 'k', 'j'])
```

The columns Ti and Tierr then give you your row-by-row means and stds of the montecarlo simulation.  The `.drop` call frees up memory from the intermediate calculations.